# How to make assertion in pyswip written to .pl file

Tags: swi-prolog

I have a pre-populated '.pl' file that contains facts and rules. I open the file using pyswip's *consult()* method. For example, there are two facts about an object's pickability:

```
pickable_object(pen).
pickable_object(paper).
```

Now after I add a new fact using pyswip:

```
prolog.assertz('pickable_object(light)')
```

The query

```
for result in prolog.query('pickable_object(X)'):
    print(result)
```

works perfectly and it prints:

> {'X': 'pen'}
>   {'X': 'paper'}
>   {'X': 'light'}

But, the assertion does not get written to the '.pl' file. How do I enable this?

As a workaround, I am simply appending the new clause string as a new line, treating as a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are interested in is saving and restoring the state of dynamic predicates between runs of Prolog, the easiest way probably is to use the [persistency library](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency). For your example, you could have the following file `myfacts_db.pl`:

```
:- module(myfacts_db,
          [ attach_myfacts_db/1,       % +File
            get_myfact/1,              % ?Fact
            set_myfact/1               % +Fact
          ]).
:- use_module(library(persistency)).

:- persistent
        myfact(fact:any).

attach_myfacts_db(File) :-
        db_attach(File, []).

get_myfact(pickable_object(pen)).
get_myfact(pickable_object(paper)).

get_myfact(Fact) :-
        myfact(Fact).

set_myfact(Fact) :-
        assert_myfact(Fact).
```

If we run Prolog with the new module for the first time, we get:

```
$ swipl

?- use_module(myfacts_db).
true.

?- attach_myfacts_db('test.pl').
true.

?- findall(X,get_myfact(pickable_object(X)),Objects).
Objects = [pen, paper].

?- set_myfact(pickable_object(light)).
true.

?- findall(X,get_myfact(pickable_object(X)),Objects).
Objects = [pen, paper, light].

?- halt.
```

The database file `test.pl` will be created if it does not yet exist. If we then start Prolog again, we have:

```
$ swipl

?- use_module(myfacts_db).
true.

?- attach_myfacts_db('test.pl').
true.

?- findall(X,get_myfact(pickable_object(X)),Objects).
Objects = [pen, paper, light].
```

Note that the database thus created is not simply a list of facts though, but looks like this (the additional stuff is used to handle synchronization):

```
$ cat test.pl
created(1565656419.9478514).
assert(myfact(pickable_object(light))).
```

If you actually want to have a file in the end that only lists the "pure" facts `pickable_object(light)).` etc., I am not aware of any built-in method of SWI-Prolog that would support that, so in that case you indeed would have to write to and read from a file by means of file I/O (or modify the DB file accordingly). This will however become tricky once you want to also support deleting facts, shared access, etc.